# PHP Shoppinf Cart Error Message

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, shopping-cart

I have an error message coming up with the following code I have used. The error message I am getting is:

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order values (34 1,1,250,2011-11-09,jahed)' at line 1
```

the code i have provided with you below starts from line 1!

```
<?php

    session_start();
    ?>
    <?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION["username"]))
    {
        header("Location: shoppinglogin.php");
    }
    ?>

    <?
        include("includes/db.php");
        include("includes/functions.php");

        if($_REQUEST['command']=='update'){
            $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
            $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
            $address=$_REQUEST['address'];
            $phone=$_REQUEST['phone'];

            $result=mysql_query("insert into customers values('','$name','$email','$address','$phone')");


        $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
            for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
                $orderid=mysql_insert_id();
                $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
                $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
                $price=get_price($pid);
                $date=date('Y-m-d');
                $user=$_SESSION['username'];
                mysql_query("insert into order values ('$orderid','$pid','$q','$price','$date','$user')")

                    or die(mysql_error());

            }
            die('Thank You! your order has been placed!');
            session_unset(); 
        }
    ?>
```

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order is a keyword. Use backtick character:

```
insert into `order` values('$orderid','$pid','$q','$price','$date','$user')
```

In general, it's good not to use keywords in table/column names (like `order`, `group`, `select` , etc)